# Debugging for camera windows 8

Tags: windows-8, camera, vmware-player

I am using Windows 8 on VMware Player and trying to get the Web camera working.

Ensured to enable the USB control and connecting device to VM instead of host.

[image]

[image]

However built in "Camera" says "There is problem with camera".

[image]

Did anyone faced this issue? or How to debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm that VMware can access your webcam, by setting up a simple Ubuntu VM and testing the webcam from there.

If the Ubuntu VM can access the webcam, but not the Windows 8 VM, then open `Device Manager` and try using a generic webcam driver.